# Black Screen when connecting via RDP

Tags: windows-7, remote-desktop

I am logging in to a windows 7 enterprise machine on a corporate network.  Occasionally when I rdp in to the machine the screen is entirely blank.  This is specific to the operator id.  If I log in with another user id the screen appears normally.  I have noticed that if I don't quit the remote session and try to log in from another machine (bumping first connection) the screen will usually go black.  I have also noticed that network issues can initiate the problem, but this is rare.  I have seen the rdp - reconnecting icon flash and than the screen go black.  Any ideas on what can be causing this problem?

One other note: processor utilization spikes to about 50% (1 core) when the screen goes black.

Answer (score 0):

1. Press <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+End</kbd>
2. Select `Start Task Manager` or cancel

First emulates <kbd>Ctrl+Alt+Del</kbd> and sends your remote console to "Option screen".
Second makes remote Windows to rethink display scheme and reset window placements.

Usually this should happen when you RDP in first time after locking screen locally, but sometimes this is not done. I believe locking local console before you leave helps to prevent such situations.